# Selenium Web Driver :findElementsBy() function of php-webdriver-bindings returning error

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I was writing the code  auto generated drop like google search help  and trying to print the values of that auto generated drop down as output.

in selenium WebDriver  to catch  multiple elements which will match with a xpath locator  we have to use findElementsBy() function,

the code i have written is given below

```
<?php 
require_once 'www/library/phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php';
class PHPWebDriverTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
 protected $webdriver;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", 4444);
        $this->webdriver->connect("firefox");
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
    //    $this->webdriver->close();
    }
    public function testgooglesearch() {                          
    $this->webdriver->get("http://google.com");
    $element=$this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "q");           
    $element->sendKeys(array("selenium" ) );
    $result=$this->webdriver->findElementsBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath,"//*[@id=\'gsr\']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[*]/td/");
    echo $countresult=count($result);

    }
}
?>
```

As per the binding findElementsBy() function will suppose to return an array. so when i am trying to count the array length  a error is returning .

**error : Trying to get property of non -object.**

can any one please help me how i can proceed.

Comment: webdriver exception is showing above that a array is printing

Comment: Which PHP bindings?  There are quite a few out there and none are officially supported by the Selenium dev team.

Comment: @Ardesco 

php binding name is  " php-webdriver-bindings"  By Lukasz Kolczynski

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At Last i am able to find the solution of the problem on my own .

My main motto was to print the value of the auto generated drop down

The main problem was the running speed of the test .As the speed of test was fast so  " findElementsBy " function was not able to work properly.

so i used sleep command just before that function so that it can work properly .

The code which work properly for me is given below

```
<?php
require_once "/phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";
class WebdriverTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

{
  protected $webdriver;

  protected function setUp()
  {   

$this->webdriver=new WebDriver("localhost", 4444);

    $this->webdriver->connect("firefox");
  }

   protected function tearDown() {
      $this->webdriver->close();
    }

  public function testSearch()
  {
    $this->webdriver->get("http://google.com");         

       $element=$this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name,"q");
    $element->sendKeys(array("selenium" ) );

sleep(2);
    $result=$this->webdriver->findElementsBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath,"//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']");
    $countresult=count($result);
    echo "Records Count = ". $countresult ."\n";
        $x=1;
    $y=0;
    echo "\n";
     while($y<$countresult)
      {
        $output=$result[$y]->getText();
    echo $output."\n";
         $x++;
         $y++;
       }

    $r=$this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath,"//div[@class='gbqlca']");
    $r->click();



    }



}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for you.

Click [here](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-get-auto-populated-google-search.html)

FYI : The above implementation is in java-selenium bindings.

Comment: @samtoshsharma 

Thanks for the link , i have checked that link but for  php-webdriver-bindings using php it is not very helpful. .

Comment: @John : yes I know , I don't know php-webdriver-bindings as I'm working with java. I suggest you that link because it may give some idea to solve your problem.